# KendoUI: resetting grid data to first page after button click

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following scenario:

in my page I have a grid (with pagination) bounded to a datasource. When I click on the button "Extract" the grid gets populated (reading paginated data through a web service). 
Then i select "page 2" through grid pagination. Again the web service is invoked to return data.

Now: I would like to click on "Extract" once more, to reload and show data on the first page. I'm not sure which is the best way.

I would like to make just one call to the service (with input parameters) and have pagination index in the grid resetted.

I am now using the following code:

```
$("#btnExtract").bind("click", function(e) {
    var grid = $("#section-table").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.read( {parameter: "value"} );
    grid.dataSource.page(1);
});
```

but it actually makes two calls to the service.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are doing server side paging it should be enough doing `grid.dataSource.page(1)` since this will invoke the `read` exactly as you already realized.

Comment: Thanks, but if I would like also to send parameters with te request?

Comment: You can add parameters to the `$grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.transport.options.read.url` property by creating the a new data source URL.

Answer (score 20):

For some reason, if the page is set to 1 and you set it to 1 again, it will do a read.  If it is something other than 1 and you set it to 1, it will just go to that page and not do a read.  So to answer your question, you can use this code:

```
if (grid.dataSource.page() != 1) {
   grid.dataSource.page(1);
}
grid.dataSource.read( {parameter: "value"} );
```

Comment: This answer worked for me and the comment marked as the solution did not.

Comment: Throw the `grid.dataSource.read({parameter:"value"});` in an `else` block to prevent a double hit to your server when the page isn't 1.

Comment: No.  If it is not page 1 you have to set it to page 1.  This will not cause a hit to the server.  Only if you set it to 1 when it is on 1 already does it hit the server.  If you don't go to page 1 first then you could end up on an empty page.

Answer (score 5):

To perform only a single request you should use the **[query](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#query)** method of the dataSource. It allows you to create combination of the different methods like filter/page/sort etc.

For example:

```
dataSource.query({ page: 5, pageSize: 20, sort: { field: "orderId", dir: "asc" } });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the DataSource.query() method to pass the page number and your custom input parameters:

```
$("#btnExtract").bind("click", function(e) {
    var grid = $("#section-table").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.query( { page: 1, parameter: "value"} );
});
```

If you're using server side paging and sorting then you may need to include that information as well:

```
$("#btnExtract").bind("click", function(e) {
    var grid = $("#section-table").data("kendoGrid");

    var queryParams = {
        page: 1,
        pageSize: grid.dataSource.pageSize(),
        sort: grid.dataSource.sort(),
        group: grid.dataSource.group(),
        filter: grid.dataSource.filter(),
        parameter: "value"
    };

    grid.dataSource.query(queryParams);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a parameterMap for your Kendo grid DataSource read operation, this comes into the transport element as shown below. Then call grid.dataSource.page(1), this will call read and you should be sorted.

```
   new kendo.data.DataSource({      
transport: {
                   read: {
                          // ur read
                          },
           parameterMap: function (o, operation) {
                         var output = null;
                         switch (operation) {
                                    case "create":
                                    break;
                                case "read":
                                    output =  {parameter: "value"};
                                    break;
                                case "update":
                                    break;
                                case "destroy":
                                    break;
                        }
                     return output;             }}});
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to define the input parameters object (I mean '{parameter: "value"}') in an external object, somewhere globally accessible, in the code? I was using "read()" just because I could update input in the parameterMap just sending data into it.