# Kendo get data from remote service, do paging locally

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

Code:

```
var url = base_url + "/api/v1/users/getUsers";
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: function (options) {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url:url,
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { searchTerm: $("#searchTerm").val().trim() },
          success: function (result) {
          options.success(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {            
          options.error(result);
        }
      });
    }
  },
  schema: {
    data: function (result) {
     return result.model;
    },
    total: function (result) {
      return result.model.length;
    },
  },
  pageSize: 5
});

$("#matches").kendoListView({
  dataSource: dataSource,
  autoBind: false, // if set to false the widget will not bind to the data source during initialization.
  template: kendo.template($("#matchesListViewTemplate").html())
});

$("#pager").kendoPager({
  dataSource: dataSource,
  autoBind: false
});

$(document).keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();      

    var searchTerm = $("#searchTerm").val().trim();
    if (searchTerm.length < 1)
      return;

    dataSource.read(); 
    dataSource.page(1); // makes another call to the remote service
  }
});
```

Because data source is remote, when we call dataSource.page(1), kendo issues another call to the remote service. This behaviour is described in this [so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508849/kendoui-resetting-grid-data-to-first-page-after-button-click):

> If you are doing server side paging it should be enough doing grid.dataSource.page(1) since this will invoke the read exactly as you already realized.

What must I change so that after I search with new searchTerm, API call would be done only once and pager would go to page 1 without making another call?

I tried with dataSource.query() but still no luck? I hope I demonstrated enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to call dataSource.page(1) when dataSource.read() gets data / is done.

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();      

    var searchTerm = $("#searchTerm").val().trim();
    if (searchTerm.length < 1)
      return;

    dataSource.read().done(function() {

      // in case remote service returns empty result set (but still http 200 code)
      // page() makes another request (if data() is empty it makes another request)
      // therefore we must check data length/total
      if( dataSource.total() > 0)
        dataSource.page(1);
    }
});
```

If the read request's response have not arrived yet or if an error occurs, another read request is allowed (in order to fetch data). DataSource.read() makes asynchronously request and then dataSource.page(1) starts to execute. DataSource.page(1) function checks if there is any data read, if it's not it executes again read method - therefore we got 2 calls as you mentioned it. Because of asynchronously call this scenario may happen.