# Kendo UI. Reset Grid to first page after sort changed

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo UI Grid with server paging and sorting. When sort is changed, grid refreshes the data, but current page remains the same.

How to catch sort event and move to first page?

*P.S. I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508849/kendoui-resetting-grid-data-to-first-page-after-button-click), but there discussed another case...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

- use the [`change`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-change) event of the Kendo UI DataSource to save the [current sort state](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-sort) in some variable.
- use the [`requestStart`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-requestStart) event to compare the previous sort state with the new sort state.
- if the sort state has changed, prevent the request with `e.preventDefault()`
- use the [`page`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-page) method to navigate to first page
- you will also need a flag variable to prevent an endless loop in the requestStart handler, as changing the page will trigger a new requestStart event

Here is a demo:

http://dojo.telerik.com/OXoYu

```
var sortState;
var resetPageFlag = false;

// ...
requestStart: function(e) {
    //console.log(e.sender.sort(), sortState);
    if (!resetPageFlag &&
        JSON.stringify(e.sender.sort()) != JSON.stringify(sortState)) {

        //console.log(e.sender.sort(), sortState);
        e.preventDefault();
        resetPageFlag = true;
        e.sender.page(1);
    } else {
        resetPageFlag = false;
    }
},
change: function(e) {
    sortState = e.sender.sort();
}
// ...
```